# Cálculos no SELECT do mySQL vs. cálculo no script

Tags: php, mysql, asp

Digamos que eu queira calcular as porcentagens de registros numa tabela mySQL para determinadas informações, como, por exemplo, usuários até 20 anos, de 21 a 30, e acima de 30 anos, e essa tabela possui uns 100 mil registros.

Em termos de **performance**, é melhor fazer os cálculos direto no SELECT ou receber as informações do banco de calcular no script PHP ou ASP, por exemplo?

Comment: com certeza no mysql porque ao contrario do php ele nao vai precisar interpretar o codigo antes de fazer o calculo.

Comment: também acho. Mas não tenho conteúdo para formular uma resposta =]

Comment: Fazer o cálculo diretamente no SELECT será mais rápido porque os dados só serão percorridos uma vez. Se você quiser fazer o cálculo no script você terá que copiar todos os dados para a memória do programa e então percorrê-los, ou seja, os dados serão lidos duas vezes. Além disso, você vai consumir muito mais memória para ter o mesmo resultado.

Comment: Usar as funções do MySQL é mais rápido do que usar o código do PHP para fazer as mesmas coisas, isso dito nesse link. PHP vs MySQL Performance - em ingles  https://onextrapixel.com/mysql-has-functions-part-5-php-vs-mysql-performance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usar as funções do MySQL é mais rápido do que usar o código do PHP para fazer as mesmas coisas, isso dito nesse link abaixo.

[PHP vs MySQL Performance - em ingles](https://onextrapixel.com/mysql-has-functions-part-5-php-vs-mysql-performance/)

[PHP vs MySQL Performance - em portugues (Google tradutor)](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=en&tl=pt&js=y&prev=_t&hl=pt-BR&ie=UTF-8&u=https%3A%2F%2Fonextrapixel.com%2Fmysql-has-functions-part-5-php-vs-mysql-performance%2F&edit-text=&act=url)

============== caso a pagina do link acima seja removida temos ==============

<sub>Sintam-se a vontade para corrigir a tradução feita pelo Google tradutor</sub>

**Metodologia de Testes**

Não há sentido em executar testes de desempenho sem algum tipo de método que tente dar resultados tão precisos quanto possível, e que tente levar em consideração quaisquer leituras anômalas. Então aqui está o exemplo:

Cada teste foi executado dentro de seu próprio script PHP para ser chamado pelo navegador. Como o código do computador é executado tão rápido, não é possível executar o código apenas uma vez para obter medições decentes. Então eu  decidi executar o código de cada teste 10.000 vezes dentro de um loop FOR .

Antes e depois de cada teste, registrei variáveis chamadas `$start` e `$end` e atribui a elas valores da função `microtime()` do PHP, que retorna um timestamp do Unix incluindo microssegundos. Sem a parte de microssegundos, o tempo não seria preciso o suficiente. O tempo gasto para as 10.000 execuções do código seria, portanto, igual a $end - $start .

**A estrutura de cada teste:**

```
    $conn = mysqli_connect(...); //connect to the DB

    ob_start(); //buffer the output, we don't actually care about seeing it

    $start = microtime(true);

    for($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++) //loop 10K times
    {
        //test code here
    }

    $end = microtime(true);

    ob_end_clean(); //get rid of the buffered output

    $time = $end - $start;
```

Para realmente executar os testes, carreguei os scripts em um dos meus servidores da Web e os executei por meio do meu navegador. Eu corri cada teste 10 vezes, em três momentos diferentes do dia, para conter quaisquer leituras anômalas causadas por coisas como processos em segundo plano que compartilhavam o tempo de CPU ou disco. Uma média de todos os tempos de execução foi então tomada.

> 

---

### ***Teste 1 - Calculando uma pontuação média***

> 

Em uma parte anterior, olhei para usar algumas das funções do MySQL para recuperar dados de uma tabela de alunos. Eu usei uma tabela de teste semelhante dessa vez e calculei a pontuação média do exame.

> Quando o MySQL calcula a média

```
    $sql = "SELECT AVG(score) as average_score FROM school";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    echo $row['average_score'];
```

Simples sim? O MySQL faz todo o trabalho na consulta, então tudo que o PHP precisa fazer é ecoar o resultado.

***Isso levou em média 2,14 segundos para 10.000 iterações.***

No PHP, no entanto, as coisas não eram tão simples.

> Quando o PHP calcula a média

O código de teste do PHP para calcular a pontuação média ficou assim:

```
    $sql = "SELECT score FROM school";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    $total = 0;

    $num = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
           $total += $row['score'];
    }

    echo ($total / $num);
```

Uma consulta um pouco mais simples, mas o código tinha que percorrer todas as linhas retornadas e totalizar todas as pontuações, depois dividir esse número pelo número de linhas via mysqli_num_rows para obter a média.

***Isso levou 5,65 segundos para executar 10.000 iterações.***

> 

---

### ***Resultado final teste 1***

> 

Portanto, para essa instância, o MySQL era 4,76 vezes mais rápido que o equivalente ao PHP.

A utilização da função AVG() do MySQL foi 2,64 vezes mais rápida que o código PHP equivalente, por isso é mais clara e mais rápida.

**Sobre o cache de consulta?**

O teste do AVG() foi executado com o cache de consulta do MySQL desabilitado, e fiquei curioso para ver se teria algum impacto nos resultados se ele estivesse ativado.

Eu assumi que os testes do MySQL terminariam ainda mais rápido, porque o cache de sua consulta significaria que nenhum cálculo do AVG() seria necessário e eu não estava errado.

Com o cache de consulta ativado e configurado para 32MB (provavelmente o overkill), o teste do MySQL demorou 0,91 segundos e o teste do PHP levou 4,27 segundos . Então desta vez o MySQL foi 4.7 vezes mais rápido que o PHP.

> 

---

### ***Teste 2 - formatar uma data***

> 

Na Parte 1 - Funções de Data e Hora , eu olhei as funções que o MySQL fornece para brincar com datas e horas, em particular a função DATE_FORMAT() , que surpreendentemente produz strings de data formatadas de maneira similar à date() do PHP date() função.

O objetivo do código nesse teste era pegar o campo de data formatada pelo MySQL (AAAA-MM-DD) de cada linha e enviá-la como uma string no formato DD / MM / AAAA .

> Quando o MySQL formata as datas

O código de teste do MySQL ficou assim:

```
$sql = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(rating_date, '%D/%M/%Y') AS rating_date FROM ratings";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo $row['rating_date'] . ' ';
}
```

Esse código levou em média 8,30 segundos para executar 10.000 iterações .

Para este teste, usei a tabela de classificações de vídeo da Parte 4, preenchida com muitos dados de amostra encantadores usando o procedimento armazenado personalizado que criei.

> Quando o PHP formata as datas

O código PHP foi mais complicado desta vez, por causa da necessidade de primeiro transformar a data do MySQL em um timestamp que poderia ser usado pela função date() do PHP.

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT rating_date FROM ratings");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $timestamp = strtotime($row['rating_date']);

    $theDate = date('d/m/Y', $ timestamp);

    echo $theDate . ' ';
}
```

Achei o resultado desse teste bastante surpreendente: o código PHP levou 39,48 segundos para ser executado 10.000 vezes.

> 

---

### ***Resultado final - Teste 2***

> 

Portanto, para essa instância, o MySQL era 4,76 vezes mais rápido que o equivalente ao PHP.

Com o cache de consulta do MySQL habilitado

Mais uma vez eu decidi executar os testes novamente com o cache de consulta habilitado e definido para 32MB.

O teste do MySQL levou 6.25 segundos e o teste do PHP levou 35.85 segundos , o que significa que o MySQL foi 5.74 vezes mais rápido.

> 

---

### ----------  Conclusão

---

> 

Usar as funções do MySQL foi mais rápido do que usar o código do PHP para fazer as mesmas coisas. Eu tinha certeza que chamar uma função MySQL seria mais rápido do que fazer um loop em um conjunto de resultados no PHP e potencialmente usar múltiplas funções do PHP para atingir o mesmo fim.

Uma coisa a ter em mente, no entanto, é que, embora o MySQL tenha sido até 5,7 vezes mais rápido do que o PHP, isso foi feito por dez mil vezes o mesmo código.

Comment: Show de bola! Era isso que eu precisava.